# Virtual Box 'VERR_SSM_LOAD_CONFIG_MISMATCH' error when restoring a snapshot

Tags: linux, windows-10, virtualbox, centos

Since I had a hard time finding an answer online, I decided to make a question here, and answer it myself, so maybe it helps someone:

I have a VirtualBox 6.1 installed on Windows 10, trying to run Centos7.

When I tried to start a VM, I got an error saying something like "**Fatal! Could not read from the boot medium**".

Then, I powered off the machine, and ticked the checkbox to restore most recent snapshot.

Restoring failed with following error text **VERR_SSM_LOAD_CONFIG_MISMATCH** :

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine CentOS7 - plus Liferay7- Template.

ahci#0: The target VM is missing a device on port 0. 
Please make sure the source and target VMs have compatible storage configurations 
[ver=9 pass=final] (VERR_SSM_LOAD_CONFIG_MISMATCH).

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

Comment: Related question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1161408/virtualbox-in-limbo-after-deleting-a-vdi-while-in-saved-state?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core of the problem for me was that virtual storage somehow got detached, so I had to re-attach it manually. Here's what I did:

- Go to the Configuration (Ctrl+S) of virtual machine
- Select Storage
- Click on icon Add Hard Disk (IDE or SATA)
- Select Choose an existing disk
- Select the file *.vdi created for your virtual machine, in the right folder
- Valid with OK
- Start your virtual machine

The VM should now boot normally.

This is how it looked like in the end for me:

[image]

Source of my fix: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/11750

Answer (score 3):

For me I just deleted the saved state and then it loaded without a problem on the next boot.

Comment: Right click, choose Discard Saved State. Boot it up afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was changing the paravirtualization interface, or for example reactivating the corresponding virtualization platform in windows features tool.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).